# How to create ascending order numbers for html elements via JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I have ten divs to which I want to assign order numbers into text via JS on the page load.

HTML:

```
<div class="generate-order-number"></div>
<div class="generate-order-number"></div>
<div class="generate-order-number"></div>
<div class="generate-order-number"></div>
...
<div class="generate-order-number"></div>
```

I have this JS code, but it's not working:

```
var currentNumber = 0;
window.onload = function generateOrderNumbers(){
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var currentNumber = currentNumber + 1;
    $('.generate-order-number:eq(' + currentNumber + ')').innerHTML = currentNumber + '.'};
};
```

so the result on the page would be like:

```
1.
2.
...
9.
10.
```

Answer (score 1):

The three issues I'm seeing are:

First, you're re-declaring `currentNumber`, which means you're never incrementing the global value:

```
var currentNumber = currentNumber + 1;
```

Don't create a new local variable, just update the global variable:

```
currentNumber = currentNumber + 1;
```

Second, you're trying to set `.innerHTML` on a jQuery object:

```
$('.generate-order-number:eq(' + currentNumber + ')').innerHTML = currentNumber + '.'
```

With jQuery you call the `.html()` function instead:

```
$('.generate-order-number:eq(' + currentNumber + ')').html(currentNumber + '.')
```

Third, the use of `:eq()` in your selector is one-based:

```
$('.generate-order-number:eq(' + currentNumber + ')')
```

But should be zero-based:

```
$('.generate-order-number:eq(' + (currentNumber - 1) + ')')
```

Otherwise the first element will be empty and the remaining ones will be numbered 1-9.

Aside from those, just to make your own code more readable and supportable I recommend cleaning up the semicolons and curly braces to be more consistent.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to achieve your code can be: (`doesn't use jQuery`)

```js
window.onload = ()=>{
  document.querySelectorAll(".generate-order-number").forEach(
    (el, i) => el.innerHTML = (i + 1) + '.'
  )
}
```